Is there a specific recommended way to handle notifications on React Native with cloud providers?
First of all, there's two "major" repositories for notifications using pure React Native, react-native-notifications, and react-native-push-notification. There are other solutions like Notifee and One Signal ,and of course, expo-notifications.
I have tried both react-native-notifications and react-native-push-notification, but like I said before, they're unmaintained and have poor documentation. Moreover with Google's recent port to their new FCM v1, I believe those packages will not function for Android anymore.
I am currently incorporating Expo into my app, because of a lot of their features that I'll be needing soon, I am just hoping for some sort of guide in the direction I need to head down to make the notification service just work for both Android and iOS considering that I will switch cloud providers.
I want to set up such a service for push notifications from my servers that it remains cloud provider agnostic, for example, I have credits from GCP right now, and soon I'll be getting some AWS credits, so after I run out on Google, I would want to port my services over to AWS with relative ease.
What I am wondering is, do I even need a cloud provider service for notifications (other than interacting with APNS or FCM of course), like AWS Amplify or Google Cloud notifications or something through Firebase directly. I've already rolled my own auth, so all I need to do when I switch cloud providers is set it up using their CLI and install their packages to my backend, and I'll be up and running again.
How can I do the same for my notification service?
